# R - reported length 200

Tags: r, csv, package, warnings

I am a student in finance from France and a newbie in statistical computing. My teacher gave me a project to do in asset management. I have to use R(version 3.2.3) in order to import files from Yahoo Finance.
I have installed the Tseries package and I realised that I cannot report the entire database. This is what I wrote :

```
accor <- get.hist.quote(instrument = "AC.PA", start = "2009-01-01", 
                        end="2015-07-27", compression="w", quote="Close")
```

And it is currently written :

```
accor <- get.hist.quote(instrument = "AC.PA", start = "2009-01-01", 
                        end="2015-07-27", compression="w", quote="Close")
essai de l'URL 'http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AC.PA&a=0&b=01&c=2009&d=6&e=27&f=2015&g=w&q=q&y=0&z=AC.PA&x=.csv'

Content type 'text/csv' length 200 bytes
    downloaded 17 KB

Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile, method = method, quiet = quiet) :
  downloaded length 18358 != reported length 200
```

I used exactly the same line at my school and it worked. The only difference is that it was on a Windows 7 computer.

I would like the whole downloaded length to be reported in order to make a decent analysis.

Sorry for my English. I hope it is understandable.

I would be grateful if someone could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `accor` have the same number of rows when you run the code on different computers? The warning might or might not mean that something went wrong. When I run your code on my Mac, it works and does not give any warnings. I get 344 rows of data. I believe the "length" in the warning message refers to bytes, rather than rows. Check to see if you're getting the same data downloaded on both computers.

Comment: The output looks right to me. You're downloading one closing value per week (`compression="w"`). So you should get 52 weeks of data per year (or maybe 51 or 53, depending on when the start of each week falls). When I set the `start` and `end` values to be 1 or more complete years, I get 52*n rows (plus or minus one or two due to the start-of-week issue), where n is the number of complete years. For example, try `start="2011-01-01"` and `end="2012-12-31"`, or a 2-year period. This gives me 105 rows, meaning 105 weeks of data.

Comment: Hello, you are right, the warning message seems to refer to bytes rather than rows. I don't know why I'm getting it on my computer. Unfortunately, I cannot see if I'm getting the same data downloaded because the school is closed for the holidays. It seems to work anyway, I'm getting 52 weeks of data per year, as you said. I can now continue my project. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with your studies.

Answer (score 1):

It is only a warning, not an error. But if you question was "how to avoid a warning" then this could help on some platforms (particularly on "windows 7 x64") to avoid a warning caused by internal call to 'download.file()' function.

```
options(download.file.method='libcurl')
```

You need to set 'download.file.method' option to 'libcurl' before the actual call of get.hist.quote or similar method.